# How to apply Condition on specific Radio Button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, getelementbyid

What I want is when I click on specific **red** id Radio Button then it shows me *Alert* as you can see in the code... in my case its not happening.. what is the issue and how can I sort this?

```html
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue
</form>
<script>
  if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    alert('working');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an eventListener

```js
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("change", myAlert); 

function myAlert() {
    alert('working');
}
```

```html
<form>
    What color do you prefer?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need event listeners - inline event handlers are not recommended
2. You need to decide what you are testing

Here are two ways to running

They are radios so we do not need to test if they are checked

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // when the page loads

  // testing clicking the RED only
  document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("The specific Red event listener was invoked");
  });    

  // delegation
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id==="red") console.log("Clicking in the form, we clicked the thing with ID red")
  })
});
```

```html
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```html
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red"/>Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue"/>Blue
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("red").onchange = function() {
   alert('working');
}
</script>
```

An event handler is needed to run that specific code when a radio button is clicked.

Comment: True. I've simplified the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Inline event handlers are not recommended

Comment: Now the event handler is not inline.